# Как ограничить свайп вниз у BottomSheet?

Tags: java, android, android-bottomsheet

Есть `BottomSheet` который по свайпу вверх выезжает с низу, и так же закрывается свайпом вниз. Дело в том что когда он закрыт, его можно утянуть вниз за экран и он пропадет. Каким образом это ограничить? Что бы свайп работал до определенной границы `BottomSheet`.
На данный момент я вообще запретил свайпы и открываю его только по клику на сам `BottomSheet`

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onNestedPreFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, View child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return false;
}
```

Вот такой `BottomSheet`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как уезжает вниз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пропишите в лейауте вашего `BottomSheet` у корневого `ViewGroup`

```
app:behavior_hideable="false"
```

Либо динамически уже в коде `bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);`

Comment: Работает, спасибо огромное!